# How to make data-target and ng-click work together

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want my a modal popup before my ng-click gets executed. But only the ng-click is executing, no pop up is displaying.

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewMapping" ng-click="onClickGenerate()">Generate Document</a>
```

addNewMapping is a div on the same view and onClickGenerate is a method on the correspnding controller.

Comment: You use bootstrap js for modals? Then this is a bad approach. Remove bootstrap.js leave only CSS and then use bootstrap ui module for this. And on your question: yes you can do it the way you are trying, but it's not worth effort, as it's a little tricky and really bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up displaying a modal popup using data-target and in the modal popup added a button to handle the ng-click event.